# Exponential Functions Proof

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I cannot find any material similar enough to this problem to be of use.

the problem states, if $$ f(x)=5^x$$

show that

$$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} = 5^x\left(\frac{5^h -1}{h}\right)$$

so I begin to work it through

$$ \frac{ 5 ^ {x+h} - 5^x}{h} = \frac{5^{x+h}}{h}- \frac{5^x}{h}$$

and the laws of exponents state that the previous can be expressed as: $$ \frac{5^x
\cdot 5^h}{h} - \frac{5^x}{h} $$

and from that point I don't see a way to get closer to the desired proof.

Comment: $$\dfrac{5^{x+h}-5^x}{h} = \dfrac{5^{x}5^h-5^x}{h} = \dfrac{5^x\left(5^{h}-1\right)}{h}= 5^x\dfrac{5^{h}-1}{h}$$

Comment: To get $5^{x+h}$ replace your parentheses with curly braces {}.

Comment: @DavidPeterson I guess I don't understand why $$5^x$$ can go from having the variable h as it's denominator to the number 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that
$$ a^{x+y}=a^x a^y $$
Then
$$ \frac{5^{x+h}-5^x}{h}= \frac{\color{red}{5^x} 5^h-\color{red}{5^x}}{h}=\color{red}{5^x}\left(\frac{5^h-1}{h}\right) $$
The last expression is reached by factoring out the $5^x$.

Comment: right in front of my eyes. - thank you